# How to copy the text from File into arraylist or map in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
var writer = PrintWriter("abc.txt")
writer.println("John")
writer.println("Emmy")
writer.println("Char")
writer.close()

var reader = File("abc.txt")
reader.forEachLine { println(it) }
```

but how can I store these names into map like john should be key and Emmy should be value

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it:

```
val list = arrayListOf<String>()
val mapNames = hashMapOf<String, String>()

val reader = File("abc.txt")
reader.forEachLine { list.add(it) }

for (i in 1..list.size / 2) {
    val key = list[2 * i - 2]
    val value = list[2 * i - 1]
    mapNames.put(key, value)
}
```

Comment: but how into map it is possible to add in Map like key will be John and value will be   Emmy

Comment: What map? Your question is about storing the lines in a list.

Comment: but i want to store in map

Comment: Then edit your question and write in details what you need

Comment: Can you please explain to me why u divided the list. size /2

Comment: If the file contains 10 names you must put in the map 10/2=5 pairs

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use a more functional approach.

```
val writer = PrintWriter("abc.txt")
writer.println("John")
writer.println("Emmy")
writer.println("Char")
writer.close()

val reader = File("abc.txt")
val mapTruncated = reader.readLines().windowed(2, 2) {
    it[0] to it[1]
}.toMap()

-> {John=Emmy}
```

`readLines()` creates an `List<String>` that conatins all lines.

`windowed(2, 2)` iterates over this list and visits 2 elements for each iteration. After an iteration it increases the current index by 2. This will truncate the last line if it's not a full window (No value for the given key).

The lambda transforamtion `{ it[0] to it[1] }` converts the window of type `List<String>` to an `Pair<String, String>`.

The resulting list (`List<Pair<String, String>>`) can be transformed to a map with `toMap()`.

---

If you want all lines and fill the last key with eg. null you cann do something like this.

```
val mapComplete = reader.readLines().chunked(2) {
    it[0] to it.getOrNull(1)
}.toMap()

-> {John=Emmy, Char=null}
```

`chunked(2)` is an alias for `windowed(2, 2, true)`. The last param `true` means it should include partial windows.